# android mpchart barchart description postion

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have a problem with description barchart in MPchart used in an Android App.

When I used the method `description.setPostion(3f, 3f)`, the description disappears.
I don't know the default value of position to customize it.

Thank you very much

[Sample image of my results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfexo.jpg)

Comment: This worked for ever and now my description is now not showing.  If I refresh the screen about 1 in 5 times is shows.  very odd.  If I use textAlign instead of setPosition it paints every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is hide in TOP_LEFT corner so use the code else not set the description postion my emulator height is 1280 and weight is 720

```
    //get the height and width of the device
    DisplayMetrics ds = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(ds);
    int width = ds.widthPixels;
    int height = ds.heightPixels;

    //set the custom description postion
    Description desc = new Description();
    desc.setText("Hai");
    desc.setTextSize(13f);
    desc.setPosition(width - 50,height - 175);
    graph.setDescription(desc);
```

The following figure "Hai" is a description of the graph

[image: Hai is a description]

desc.setPosition(width - 50,height - 1250);//Fig:2 Description is display in right most corner

[image: position Top Right just change the number]

"Hai" Text is Description